# Listar usuarios deshabilitados (baja lógica) de linux

Tags: linux, bash

Como dice el titulo, necesito saber si puedo listar los usuarios que se encuentran deshabilitados. Es decir, obviamente no borrados, sino que bloqueado su acceso al sistema. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes consultarlos ejecutando el siguiente comando desde la terminal:

```
sudo passwd -S -a |awk '/LK/{print $1}'
```

En el código estamos buscando la palabra LK, que nos indica que el usuario estaría bloqueado, este proceso quizá podría variar un poco de acuerdo a la distribución de linux.

También con este otro comando podrás consultar todos los usuarios:

```
sudo passwd -S -a | grep " L " | cut -d " " -f1
```

O también con:

```
compgen -u
```

Comment: perdon por no contestar antes. pero muchas gracias por la mano!

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda